# Customer name always "guest" for PayPal Express/User name not save

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

When I get an order from PayPal Express the customer name in the confirmation mail is always "Guest". I checked the mail template and there it says `{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}`.

I tried calling this from normal code like this:

```
$n = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id)->getCustomerName();
var_dump($n);
```

This also returns "Guest" for the Express order. How is it possible to get the real name for a PayPal Express order, just like for the other orders with different payment methods?

Comment: Same issue in Magento 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If user name not show in admin when place an order with paypal express as guest.

Please find below file and replace code(For best practice override Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout class):
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php

```
protected function _prepareGuestQuote()
{
    $quote = $this->_quote;
    $quote->setCustomerId(null)
        ->setCustomerFirstname($quote->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname()) 
        ->setCustomerLastname($quote->getBillingAddress()->getLastname())
        ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
        ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
        ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
    return $this;
}
```

[reference](http://magentoabid.blogspot.in/2015/04/magento-paypal-express-bug-guest-user.html)